# How to fix gradle build error: Could not get property 'androidXTestVersion0' for object

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

I'm trying to set up instrumented unit testing for an android app by following the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup). I've verified that the google maven repository is listed in the repositories section of the gradle.build file and added the following to the dependencies section:

```
// Core library
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestVersion0"

// AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$testRulesVersion"

// Assertions
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testJunitVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:$truthVersion"

// Espresso dependencies
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espressoVersion"
```

I can't share anymore of the gradel.build file.

When I try to build the project or perform a gradle sync I get the following error:

```
Could not get property 'androidXTestVersion0' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I'm new to android so any additional information that can be included in answers to further my understanding of gradle builds and help me gain insight into why this error is happening is welcome.